# Retrieve rows less than a day old

Tags: mysql, timestamp, conditional-statements

I have a column `date`, which has a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, eg: `2011-11-16 15:34:02`. Is there any way to put a condition in the mysql statement (not in php) to retrieve rows which are less than a day old? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders where date > 24 hours ago
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`timestampadd()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) to get the timestamp for 24 hours ago

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE `date` > timestampadd(hour, -24, now());
```

This is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE `date` > timestampadd(day, -1, now());
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Note the backticks around `date`, as it's a reserved word.

Comment: Not necessary. Try `select now() + interval 1 day`. You'll get a 'tomorrow' answer.

Comment: I think you want `>` instead of `=`.

Comment: @macek: at the time I wrote my answer, OP's question was "which are a day old".

Comment: Interesting - learn something new every day - found that syntax in the middle of the DATE_ADD docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

yup, combine *date_sub* with *interval 1 day* and *curdate()* and maybe something else
see documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the difference directly with [`timestampdiff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function witch is similar to `timestampadd`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date, NOW()) > 24;
```

I think this can't as optimized as using `timestampadd` (because it calculate the difference for each row) but it's, in my opinion, more readable and an alternative if you don't care about optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

This statement returns all today's rows:

```
select * from orders where date_field >= CURDATE();
```

[`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) returns today's date, so searches the records starting from midnight.