# VB.net SQL statement to query 1 yr old Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, sysdate

I want to display in my gridview all data whose timestamp is not older than 1 years from current date.

My timestamp is formatted like so: `20110125-071830` or `yyyymmdd-hhmmss`

**I have tried to reference :**

[Retrieve rows less than a day old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154564/retrieve-rows-less-than-a-day-old):

```
Select *  from table_name WHERE DATE(timestampVal) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

but got missing expression flag

I also tried various others; however, my timestampVal is different simply by how it is formatted.

Like for example: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2207956

With coding:  `Select *  from table_name WHERE timestampVal < sysdate - interval '1' year ;`

but get error: `literal does not match format string` which means sysdate can't read how mine is formatted.

How do I query my timestamp to pull all that are a year or less old?

FYI: timestampVal is string type [varchar]

Comment: What is the data type of `timestampVal`?

Comment: @BobJarvis varchar which I know needs to somehow be converted and I have tried a few Converts but it isn't working. I will make note in my post that it is a string type

Comment: Are all of these strings formatted the same or are they different? Please supply a sample of the values in your question. Thanks.

Comment: The sample is listed at beginning of post. They are all formatted the same @BobJarvis

Comment: You really should use the correct data type, such as `TIMESTAMP`.  `varchar` is inappropriate for date and time values, especially if you're going to be doing comparisons over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following should work:

```
Select *
  from table_name
  WHERE TO_DATE(timestampVal, 'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS') > sysdate - interval '1' year;
```

Also note that I reversed the comparison: you indicated that you want rows where `timestampVal` is **not older** than 1 year ago - so `timestampVal` should be greater (newer) than current time minus one year.

Give that a try.

Best of luck.

Comment: I literally was just playing with TO_DATE but my stuff in the ' ' were different. It looks to be running but after a while of running I get an error flag of `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` so not sure why but I don't think it is because of your code. If you don't mind me asking, lets say my one year is specified [aka stop before 2013]?

Comment: However, the answer you gave me does work. So thank you for helping me

Comment: Keep in mind that while an approach like this may yield the correct results, it is  [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and thus will result in a table scan. It cannot use an index because it has to convert the field from each and every row of the table individually to evaluate the left-side of the expression.  Performance will suffer as the size of the table increases.

Comment: @MattJohnson - agree completely. One thing to try would be to create a function-based index - but the best thing to do would be to convert `timestampVal` to DATE.