# VB.net Minus 1 year from DateTime.Now.ToString

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, tostring

Based on my previous question, [VB.net SQL statement to query 1 yr old Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586341/vb-net-sql-statement-to-query-1-yr-old-timestamp) , my SQl query to look back a year of records gets stopped half way with the following error: `Select Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`.

Therefore, I decided to do a different route to rows that are not older than a year from current date.

To do this I will make the following SELECT statement in VB.net:

```
Dim strSearch As String = "Select timestampVal from table_name WHERE timestampVal > " & minusYear & " order by timestampVal DESC"
```

For my `minusYear` variable in my SELECT statement, I will first pull the following current date string:

```
Dim sign As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss")
```

However, to get `minusYear` I need to somehow minus a year from `sign`.

I tried `Dim minusYear As String = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)`; however it formats it like so `MM\DD\YYYY HH:MI:SS PM` which won't work since I need to query where the string looks like `yyyyMMdd-hhmmss`.

**Is there a way to simply minus 1 year from my sign string?** I try to but there is of course datatype issues and converting the string to `CInt` doesn't really work.

If I can get the 1 year minus sign to get `minusYear`, then my select statement works [I have tested it in SQL so this way will work, I just need to get `sign's` value minus a year]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a code-smell to do the manipulation at the app layer instead of the SQL. I'd persist a little more on that first question if you can (I'll take a look next). But in the meantime, to do it in VB.NET...

```
Dim sign As String = DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Now()).ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss")
```

Comment: I updated after seeing your comment about the string format. This now formats it like you wanted. However, again this is a code-smell. You should not be building up SQL query strings. If you create a parameterized-query and pass in the parameter as a DateTime instead of a String, then you never have to worry about the format of the date.

Comment: This does work how I wanted. thanks. The issue is the database was pre-created prior to me working on the application. The application has 1000+ of information in the date column and thus; I have to work with what information was implemented. they all look like they follow the same format; however, the database flag when I try to do this in there prevents me with the error I mentioned above. With that being said, I knew that applying the query in VB.net didn't flag the errors. So even though I prefer to do my query within the database, I can't bypass the error. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- In .NET, format strings are case sensitive.  You've specified `hh`, which are hours on a 12-hour clock.  You probably meant `HH` for hours on a 24-hour clock.
- It's much easier to subtract a year with `DateTime.Now.AddYear(-1)`, though keep in mind that `DateTime.Now` is in the local time zone of your server.  In many cases, that's a problem unto itself.  Depending on your data, you might consider using `DateTime.UtcNow`, or possibly using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz)` to convert to a specific time zone instead of relying on the server's time zone setting.
- Really, you should not store dates or times as `varchar` in the database.  Use a `TIMESTAMP` field in oracle.  All of the formating issues you have stem from there.  Create a new column, migrate the data, update your usages, and remove the old column.
- You should also not pass parameters by string concatenation.  That is often bad for performance (preventing caching of the execution plan), and can sometimes [make your code vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).
- When you [pass parameters properly on the .NET side](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter), rather than embedding them in the string, the string representation format becomes irrelevant.
- Unless there's something specific in your application layer that you need to account for, really you should not be doing this at all.  Instead, use the functions in your database to calculate the current time and subtract a year there.  Sending the current time as a parameter to your database is pointless, as your database can do that itself.